# Populate dropdown lists on page load in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, drop-down-menu

This is the array list I want to populate in my dropdown list.

```
  ArrayList<FriendRequestBean> friendRequests = (ArrayList<FriendRequestBean>) session.getAttribute("friendRequests");
```

but when I click on the dropdown list icon, its empty. What is the solution to it. I want it to be done like in facebook notifications.

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Friend Requests">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <%
                            for(int i=0; i<friendRequests.size(); i++){
                        %>
                        <li>
                         <a href="#"><%=friendRequests.get(i).getRequestSender() %> User</a>
                        </li>

                        <% } %>

                    </ul>
                </li>
           </ul>
```

here is the code for Servlet/controller

```
  session.setAttribute("loginSuccess", user);

  friendRequests = FriendRequestBAL.showFriendRequests(user.getUserID());

  session.setAttribute("friendRequests", friendRequests);

  RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Index.jsp");

                                    rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: post the controller/page where you are getting the session stuff from so we can help better.

Answer (score 1):

You need a reference to the data.When you are returning the view(guessing you are using controllers) you should be adding the data(friendRequests) to the model object  and then you can access it in the view file(.jsp); you typically dont want Java code in your JSP file.

example:Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model,HttpServletRequest request) {
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );
    return "home";
}
```

now home is the view(home.jsp) so we have this inside the jsp file.

```
Welcome
it is now ${serverTime}.
```